# How to find the indexes of 10% of the highest samples in a vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector with real numbers only. The length of the vector is 5000 samples. I would like to find the indexes of the 10% of the highest samples (meaning 500 samples in total). Any idea of how to do that in Matlab?

Comment: You can use this:https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23576-min-max-selection?focused=6348501&tab=function MATLAB is also releasing their own version soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
x = 1:100; 
v = prctile(x,90);
res = find(x>v)
```

I put 90 in `v` because you were looking for the top 10%, that is, the 90-th percentile. The `x` above is just an example, you can replace it with your `x`.

Comment: NB: `prctile` requires the Statistics Toolbox.

Answer (score 5):

first of all sort the sample in descending order and then select the top 10 percent:

```
[sortedVector, idxs] = sort(vector,'descend');
sampleRange = 1:floor(0.1*length(vector));
sample = sortedVector(sampleRange);
idxsSample = idxs(sampleRange);
```

Comment: Does not require any additional toolboxes. +1.